# getting value from a link in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, anchor, forms, http-request-parameters

I have  anchor-link in jsp page as shown below inside the `<td>` in table.

```
<td>
    <span>
        <a href="AddDescriptionForEvent.jsp?" name="count"><%=(cnt)%></a>
    <span>
</td>
```

here `cnt` inside scriplet is an integer. The tags are in the `<form>` and `action` attribute of the `<form>` is directing to the correct next page.
I have to take the value of that integer in the next page.

I am using like below,

```
int day = nullIntconv(request.getParameter("count"));
```

here `nullIntconv` will convert `string` to `integer`.

but I am not getting the value which I selected. It is giving me 0 always.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some changes in your href ,
a href doesn't submit as a form element(eg- textbox,textarea etc..)

Try using like this..

```
<td><span> <a href="AddDescriptionForEvent.jsp?count=<%=(cnt)%>">Click to get count</a><span></td>
```

In Above count will send as a query string
On the next page read count from request ...

```
String c= request.getParameter("count");
if(c!=null)
{
int count=Integer.parseInt(c);//converting back into integer
}
```

-----your custom code here----------

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` cannot be used as you think you can. It is not one of the HTML elements which is dependent on a `<form>` for a submit like `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` etc.

You can read more about using `<a>` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) and about how to pass request-parameters in a URL [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Also somethings about [HTML form and its elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

so if your code is something like this:

```
<form action="/AddDescriptionForEvent.jsp" name="myForm">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="someText" value="some Value" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>
            <a href="AddDescriptionForEvent.jsp?" name="count"><%=(cnt)%></a>
        <span>
    </td>

    <input type="submit" value="Press me to Submit" />
</form>
```

Then on-clicking of the `submit` button you would only be sending the value of the input `someText` and not of `count`.
To send the value of `count` with other values make the following form:

```
<form action="/AddDescriptionForEvent.jsp" name="myForm">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="someText" value="some Value" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>
            <!-- changed the <a> tag to <input> -->
            <input type="text" name="count" value="<%=(cnt)%>" />
        <span>
    </td>

    <input type="submit" value="Press me to Submit" />
</form>
```

or you can just use the following without the `<form>`:

```
<td>
    <span>
        <a href="AddDescriptionForEvent.jsp?count=<%=cnt%>">Click this link to Add</a>
    <span>
</td>
<!-- Notice the placement of the "cnt" variable of JSP -->
```

To also pass the other parameter on click of this `<a>` link, modify the `href` to `href="AddDescriptionForEvent.jsp?count=<%=cnt%>&someText=some value"`

These are the two way you can achieve your desired result. Your java code to fetch request-parameter is fine.

Answer (score 0):

<%=(cnt)%>

Instend of

use

" name="count"><%=(cnt)%>

Answer (score 0):

```
   thanks for all your replies.

     I did like this in the main page, added id
     <td align="center" height="35" id="day_<%=(cnt)%>">
     <span><a href="AddDescriptionForEvent.jsp?id=<%=(cnt)%>"><%=(cnt)%></a></span></td>

     And in the next page i got the required output as

     int d=nullIntconv(request.getParameter("id"));

        Where nullIntconv is the string to integer converter.
```